# Install MySql from an exe file with c#

Tags: c#, mysql, installation, exe

I'm stuck with this issue, and so far haven't found any solution.

I have a c# program that uses a MySQL database. Is there any way that I can generate the setup of that program that also install MySQL server and auto generate the database??

Comment: Build a setup that will install components. One is the MySql server and the other your application.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use a MySQL database? Check out [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/), it has the same base features as MySQL (Select, Update, etc.) but the difference is you do not need a server, the database is in a single file, so you can just include that file in your project and have a ready to use database.